# Is the following true regarding integration?

Tags: integration

Is the following correct?

$$ \int_{x}^{+\infty} \left(f(u)-g(u)\right) du = \int_{x}^{+\infty} f(u)du  - \int_{x}^{+\infty} g(u) du$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both integrals on the right hand side exist, yes. Or more generally, if two of the three integrals exist, the other also exists an the equality holds.

Comment: I have a function where if I compute the integral over the difference $\int f(u)-g(u)$ it is convergent integral while if I compute individually each of the integrals would diverge, does that make sense?

Comment: Then the right hand side is not defined, and consequently the equality does not hold..

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by the integral is not defined

Comment: The right hand side is not defined because both integrals diverge. Assuming they are both equal to $+\infty$, what would $+\infty-(+\infty)$ mean?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its true since integration is nothing but limit of summation

and this limit of summation should exist for each of the function

Comment: Suppose $f(u) = g(u)$, but $f$ (and hence $g$) is not integrable? Then $\int_x^{+\infty} f(u)\,du$ doesn't make sense, so the right hand side might not even be defined.

Comment: the meaning of "limit of summation should exist" means that each f and g must be integrable @Tom

Comment: I have a function where if I compute the integral over the difference $\int f(u)-g(u)$ it is convergent integral while if I compute individually they diverge.

Comment: @Tyrone that's what I meant in the previous comment that the functions f and g must be integrable individually.