# How to compute or simplify this integration?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Any hints on solving an integration of the following form,

$$\int_{x}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+sy^{-1}}\right) \left(\text{exp}(-\sqrt{y})+ y^{-\frac{1}{2}}(1-\text{exp}(-\sqrt[4]y)\right)dy $$

This arises pretty much in Poisson point processes after using the probability generating function property.

I know the above looks pretty much hopeless, I tried using Mathematica and Wolfram Alpha, both don't really help much.

I also have $x>0$ and $s>0$ real numbers if that helps.

I tried the following [Wolfram|Alpha input](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%5B%20%281-1%2F%281%2Bs*y%5E%28-1%29%29%29%20*%20%20%28exp%28-sqrt%28y%29%29%20%2By%5E%28-0.5%29%20*%20%281-%20exp%28-y%5E%280.25%29%29%29%20%29%20%5D) and it gives a result in terms of $i$ imaginary, I don't understand why.

Also is there any valid approximation for which I can say that this integral can be approximately upper and lower bound by?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: i see no chance to integrate this

Comment: even numerically ? @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: yes if $s$ is given

Comment: You were given the first part in a previous question in terms of the Ei function, if I remember correctly, so why include it again?

Comment: "This arises pretty much in poisson point processes" Really? Care to explain how this does?

Comment: Take for example the following $$\mathbb{E} \left(\prod_{x\in \Phi}v(x)\right) = \text{exp}\left(-\int [1-v(x)]\Lambda(dx)\right)$$ the integral I present above is of the same form where $v(x) = \frac{1}{1+sx^{-1}}$ and the rest is my intensity @Did

Comment: A nicer representation of the integral can be found by making the obvious substitution $t = \sqrt[4]{y}$ then $I = 4s\int_{\sqrt[4]{x}}^\infty \frac{1}{s+t^4}\left(t^3e^{-t^2} + t - te^{-t}\right)dt$. From this it seems hopeless to get an analytical answer I'm afraid. Perhaps when $x=0$ and some special values for $s$. Try numerical integration!

Comment: The connection to Poisson processes seems flimsy at best (why this intensity $\Lambda$?).

Comment: My problem involves a "not so nice intensity" $\Lambda$ since I have two types of intensities within, for example the above can be thought of $\Lambda_1$ with a certain probability while $\Lambda_2$ with another probability. This probability is of the form $\text{exp}(-cy)$. @Did

Comment: @Did As for your other comment about Ei given in my previous question, turns out I can't separate the integration individually because not each function is not defined. i.e if I do each indiviually my function would diverge while as I present here it would diverge http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996897/is-the-following-true-regarding-integration/996903#996903

Comment: Except that here, both parts *converge*.

Comment: Nope notice that I have $y^{-0.5} $

Comment: @Did check my question here, you commented on it, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995631/help-in-evaluating-the-integral-at-the-given-limits

Comment: The prefactor makes it $y^{-3/2}$. Hence, convergent at $+\infty$.

Comment: So can I do the following $$\int_{x}^{+\infty}\left(\text{exp}(-\sqrt{y})+ y^{-\frac{1}{2}}(1-\text{exp}(-\sqrt[4]y)\right)dy -\int_{x}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+sy^{-1}} \left(\text{exp}(-\sqrt{y})+ y^{-\frac{1}{2}}(1-\text{exp}(-\sqrt[4]y)\right)dy $$ @Did

Comment: ?? Precisely what you should do to get two diverging integrals. Please study calmly my previous comments, the converging integrals are $$\int_{x}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+sy^{-1}}\right)\exp(-\sqrt{y})dy\qquad  \int_{x}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+sy^{-1}}\right)y^{-\frac{1}{2}}(1-\exp(-\sqrt[4]{y}))dy $$

Comment: Oh yes your right, tried the first integral you write down above using wolfram alpha , I dont understand why I get imaginary within the Ei, do you have any ideas?@Did

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18270/discussion-between-tyrone-and-did).